# jquery-mobile - prevent scrolltop on loading a new page into the DOM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, css-transitions

I want to override Jquery Mobile scrolling to the top of the screen on changing a page.

There are two transitions I need to tweak:
a) transitions between two pages already existing in the DOM (see Jquery Mobile RC2.js line #2440)
b) transitions when a new page is added to the DOM

I'm halfway done: 
You can block **(a)** by overriding the 4 scrollTo() following after line #2440.

**Question:**
Which section in JQM.js do I need to tweak when I want to override ScrollTo when a new page is loaded? Just can't find it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQM offers `$.mobile.silentScroll`

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

> Scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event
>   listeners.
>
> - Arguments: yPos (number, defaults to 0).
>
> Pass any number
>   to scroll to that Y location.

Examples:

```
//scroll to Y 100px             
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

Comment: Thx. But I'm looking for the code in JQM.js which performs this silentScroll when I'm loading a new page vs. when I'm transitioning between two pages already in the DOM.  

Maybe this makes it clearer: I have a JQM page. Attached to its fixed footer is a popup menu, which can hold nested JQM pages. When I changepage inside the menu loading a new page, I don't want to scrollTop on the background page. I can block this silentscroll when I'm transitioning between two pages existing (in the menu), but not when I load a new page into the menu.

Comment: me again. Found it, but it's not related to scrollTop. It is inside the fixedToolbars HIDE function, in which I modified the thisCSStop check. Thx anyway.